# delete 50% of the lines containing a specific string in a specific column using shell

Tags: shell

I have a data file which has many rows and columns. I want to randomly delete exactly 50% of the lines which contain the number '2' in the second column. How can I do this in shell script? My file looks something like this:

```
264 2 -1.2000000000000000e+00 7.0825130926872939e+00 9.5601084339752944e+00 7.2651799153974066e+00 
245 4 2.3999999999999999e+00 3.2314933672268427e+00 8.1060222635488888e+00 4.9300995049182887e+00
602 2 2.3999999999999999e+00 7.9943142143951045e+00 8.9555257846190486e+00 6.1149829552712900e+00 
323 3 -1.2000000000000000e+00 9.5688081384508621e+00 1.0611671606914694e+01 8.9952891594417164e+00 
45 3 -1.2000000000000000e+00 9.4185463105240714e+00 9.3227605688201560e+00 6.6654941991009027e+00  
103 2 2.3999999999999999e+00 1.0178713184773681e+01 1.0522860587449216e+01 7.5396990175229996e+00 
462 2 2.3999999999999999e+00 4.2166316392533885e+00 6.9152554630316221e+00 7.5523911902369765e+00 
239 3 -1.2000000000000000e+00 7.8204053112970211e+00 8.2536094294868985e+00 9.4685060963111152e+00 
598 3 -1.2000000000000000e+00 7.9895230606907504e+00 7.3376809962958367e+00 6.1930783591087541e+00
```

Comment: Could you use perl or sed or awk?  or are you really restricted to bash/shell?

Comment: I can use awk or sed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your data is in a file called `input`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand()} $2!=2 || int(2*rand()) {print}' input
```

Explanation:

- `BEGIN{srand()}`

  This selects a random seed for the random number generator.  This is done once before `awk` starts looping through each line of the file.
- `$2!=2 || int(2*rand()) {print}`

  In `awk`, this a statement with a condition.  The statement is `print` which will print the whole of the current line but only if the condition is true.  The condition has two parts which are or-d together.  The condition is true if the second column has any value other than 2:  `$2!=2`.  Alternatively, it is true if `int(2*rand())` evaluates to non-zero which happens randomly with a 50-50 chance.

  Thus, about half of the lines whose second column is equal to 2 are randomly deleted.

#### Getting *exactly* half

If one keeps the `$2==2` lines with a 50-50 chance, one won't keep exactly 50%, just like flipping a fair coin won't give *exactly* 50% heads.  The following code compensates for that keeping, assuming an even number of affected lines, exactly 50%:

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand()}
     NR==FNR && $2==2 {a[j++]=rand()}
     NR==FNR {next}
     FNR==1 {n=asort(a,b); cutoff=b[n/2]}
     $2!=2 {print; next}
     a[i++]<=cutoff {print}' input input
```

*How it works*: The above goes through the file twice.  On the first go through, it assigns a random number to each line for which `$2==2`.  These values are stored in the array `a`.  At the start of the second go-through, these numbers are sorted and a cutoff value is assigned.  Any `$2==2` line whose random number is less than or equal to the cutoff is printed.

Because this uses the `asort` function, GNU `awk` is required.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but with this strategy there’s no guarantee of having a 50% deletion. You can end with no “2” lines (or with all of them).

Comment: I agree with @klashxx. Its giving me random results, sometimes I have no 2s sometime I have 50% and sometime I have more than 50%. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Rafat In your question, it was said that there were "many rows."  If there are "many," then this algorithm will give you close to half deleted.  Flips of a fair coin behave similarly: after many flips, it is unlikely that _exactly_ half will be heads but close to half will be.  If you need exactly half, then maybe klashxx's approach is better for you.

Comment: @Rafat I just added a version that does exactly 50%.

Answer (score 2):

To guarantee at ~50% deletion we will need to know (in advance) who many “rows” are storing the “2” values.

```
awk 'function get_random(total) {
        while(1){
           a = sprintf(int(total * rand()))
           if (!( a in b )){
              b[a]++
              if (++i>int(total/2))
                 break
              }
           }
        }
     BEGIN{srand();k=0}
     NR==FNR{if ($2==2){total++};next}
     !i{get_random(total)}
     $2!=2{print;next}
     (sprintf(++k) in b){print}' inputfile inputfile
```

`get_random` : will get as parameter the number of records affected, the while loop it’s going to store total/2 (random an non-repeated) values in an associative array (b) (using transformation to string)

`NR==FNR{if ($2==2){total++};next}` :number of occurrences where second field equal to 2.

`!i{get_random(total)}` :call to the function when counter `i` is null and we're on the second iteration of the file.

`$2!=2{print;next}` :print non affected rows

`(sprintf(++k) in b){print}` :  filter rows print only if counter is in array (filled with random values).

Comment: I made a test file and tried to implement your script on it, but its strange that sometimes its giving me 50% deletion sometimes its giving less. Was it supposed to be like this?